# ActionScript 3 - If then statement

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I am working with Actionscript3 and I am using codes to show information. So when I show the code, the camera picks it up and it re-directs them to a specific part of the timeline. I have all of this working but each code has a specific ID, and I want each ID to be taken to a different spot on the timeline. Currently this is my code:

```
tuioManager.addEventListener(TuioEvent.ADD, addMarker);


function addMarker(e:TuioEvent){

trace("I see :"+ (e.tuioContainer as TuioObject).classID);
if (1) gotoAndPlay('Navigate');

if (2) gotoAndPlay('NavigateB');
 }
```

It picks up on the different ID's ( from the trace function) but I dont know how to specify the code number - I have tried using if (2) but I dont think that is right. Any ideas on how to do it? THANKS

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is use the classID as the condition of the if statement

```
function addMarker(e:TuioEvent){

    trace("I see :"+ (e.tuioContainer as TuioObject).classID);
    var classID:int =(e.tuioContainer as TuioObject).classID; 
    if (classID==1) gotoAndPlay('Navigate');
    else if (classID==2) gotoAndPlay('NavigateB');
}
```

Alternatively you can use a switch statement.